# $5$ divides one of $x,y,z$ in $x^2+y^2=z^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

1) If $x$, $y$, and $z$ are positive integers for which $gcd(x,y,z) =1$ and $x^2+y^2=z^2$, show that $3$$∣$$xy$.

2) Now again if $x$, $y$, and $z$ are positive integers for which $gcd(x,y,z) =1$ and $x^2+y^2=z^2$, can a similar result to the one in (part 1) be said mod $5$? Not that $5$$∣$$xy$, but that $5$ divides one of $x,y,z$?

I believe I have 1) down:

We note that $3$ is a prime, so $3∣xy⟺3∣x$ or $3∣y$. Suppose to the contrary that $3∤x$, and $3∤y$, then:$x=1$, $2$ mod $3$ and $y=1$, $2$ mod $3$. Then:

$x^2+y^2=2$ mod $3$, and $z^2=0$, $1$ mod $3$. Contradiction, proving the claim.

But I am having trouble with 2). Can anyone show a solution for 2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Squares are $0,1$ or $-1\bmod 5$

If both $x$ and $y$ are not multiples of $5$ then $x^2\equiv \pm 1$ and $y^2\equiv \pm 1\bmod 5$

This implies $x^2+y^2\equiv -2,0$ or $2\bmod 5$.

Of course, since $x^2+y^2$ is a square it must be $0\bmod 5$ given the previous options.

Comment: Ah! I figured out what I was missing, as a result of your post. Thank you!

Comment: YACWMF${}{}{}{}$

Comment: What is YACWMF?

Comment: @Crazed you are completely welcome my friend

Answer (score 0):

For the second part since $5$ is prime, if $5 \mid xy \implies 5 \mid x$ or $5\mid y$. For the first part, we have: $x = 2mn, y = m^2-n^2=(m-n)(m+n)$. Thus if $3 \nmid x$, then $3 \nmid m, 3 \nmid n$. Thus if $m = n \pmod 3$, then $m-n = 0 \pmod 3$, otherwise say $m = 1\pmod 3, n = 2\pmod 3 \implies m+n = 0 \pmod 3$.